# Swift - How do I use auto layout with items in a ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, ios-autolayout

I'm having some trouble with adding in items to a scroll view. Right now I've added all of my items programmatically into the scroll view but am running into some issues with auto layout. I don't fully understand how to add items into the scroll view without doing all the programming I'm doing or at least by adding some form of auto layout so it doesn't look so bad on different devices. Please let me know if you can help. My code is below.

Thanks ahead!

P.S. The Textfields are added in a separate function.

P.S.S. Some images are text but they are used as images because you can't format them in iOS to have the desired appearance I'm aiming for.

```
/*
 ManagePages - This section handles the UIScrollView
 */
private func managePages()
{
    self.sideScrollView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.view.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height)
    let scrollViewWidth:CGFloat = self.sideScrollView.frame.width
    let scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = self.sideScrollView.frame.height

    let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:(scrollViewWidth/2) - (129/2), y:157,width:129, height:84))
    imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "Image1")
    imgOne.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:((((scrollViewWidth*2)/4))*3)-(153/2), y:137,width:153, height:153))
    imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "Image2")
    imgOne.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let imgThree = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:((((scrollViewWidth*3)/6))*5)-(132/2), y:137,width:132, height:151))
    imgThree.image = UIImage(named: "Image3")
    imgOne.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let imgFour = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:((((scrollViewWidth*4)/8))*7)-(139/2), y:137,width:139, height:118))
    imgFour.image = UIImage(named: "Image4")
    imgOne.contentMode = .center
    let imgFive = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:((((scrollViewWidth*5)/10))*9)-(171/2), y:127,width:171, height:169))
    imgFive.image = UIImage(named: "Image5")
    imgOne.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let imgSix = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:((((scrollViewWidth*6)/12))*11)-(133/2), y:127,width:133, height:175))
    imgSix.image = UIImage(named: "Image6")
    imgSix.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    let messageOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: (137+153+25), width: scrollViewWidth, height: 112))
    messageOne.image = UIImage(named: "Message1")
    messageOne.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    let titleOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (scrollViewWidth/2) - (131/2), y:57, width: 131, height: 56))
    titleOne.image = UIImage(named: "Title1")
    titleOne.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let titleTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:(((scrollViewWidth*2)/4)*3)-(184/2), y: 57, width:184, height: 56))
    titleTwo.image = UIImage(named: "Title2")
    titleTwo.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let titleThree = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:(((scrollViewWidth*3)/6)*5)-(227/2), y: 57, width:227, height: 56))
    titleThree.image = UIImage(named: "Title3")
    titleThree.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let titleFour = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:(((scrollViewWidth*4)/8)*7)-(scrollViewWidth/2), y: 57, width:scrollViewWidth, height: 56))
    titleFour.image = UIImage(named: "Title4")
    titleFour.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let titleFive = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:(((scrollViewWidth*5)/10)*9)-(270/2), y: 57, width:270, height: 56))
    titleFive.image = UIImage(named: "Title5")
    titleFive.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let titleSix = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:(((scrollViewWidth*6)/12)*11)-(270/2), y: 57, width:270, height: 56))
    titleSix.image = UIImage(named: "Title6")
    titleSix.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    for (index,element) in inputFields.enumerated()
    {
        if(index == 0)
        {
            element.frame = CGRect(x: calculateTextFieldXLocation(pageNumber: 1, scrollWidth: scrollViewWidth, width: 244), y: 222, width: 244, height: 49)
            element.background = UIImage(named:"SetupTextField")
            element.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 24.0)
            element.textAlignment = .center
            element.keyboardType = .emailAddress
            element.autocapitalizationType = .none
            element.placeholder = "Email"
            element.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        }
        else if(index == 1)
        {
            element.frame = CGRect(x: calculateTextFieldXLocation(pageNumber: 1, scrollWidth: scrollViewWidth, width: 244), y: 327, width: 244, height: 49)
            element.background = UIImage(named:"SetupTextField")
            element.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 24.0)
            element.textAlignment = .center
            element.isSecureTextEntry = true
            element.placeholder = "Password"
            element.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            element.returnKeyType = .done
        }
        else if(index == 2)
        {
            element.frame = CGRect(x: calculateTextFieldXLocation(pageNumber: 2, scrollWidth: scrollViewWidth, width: 244), y: 222, width: 244, height: 49)
            element.background = UIImage(named:"SetupTextField")
            element.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 24.0)
            element.textAlignment = .center
            element.placeholder = "First Name"
            element.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            element.returnKeyType = .done
        }
        else if(index == 3)
        {
            element.frame = CGRect(x: calculateTextFieldXLocation(pageNumber: 2, scrollWidth: scrollViewWidth, width: 244), y: 327, width: 244, height: 49)
            element.background = UIImage(named:"SetupTextField")
            element.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 24.0)
            element.textAlignment = .center
            element.placeholder = "Last Name"
            element.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            element.returnKeyType = .done
        }
        else if(index == 4)
        {
            element.frame = CGRect(x: (scrollViewWidth*3)-(scrollViewWidth/2)-(122), y: 432, width: 244, height: 49)
            element.background = UIImage(named:"SetupTextField")
            element.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 24.0)
            element.textAlignment = .center
            element.placeholder = "Date of Birth"
            element.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            addDatePicker(element: element)
        }
        else if(index == 5)
        {
            element.frame = CGRect(x: (scrollViewWidth*3)-(scrollViewWidth/2)-(122), y: 534, width: 244, height: 49)
            element.background = UIImage(named:"SetupTextField")
            element.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 24.0)
            element.textAlignment = .center
            element.placeholder = "Gender"
            element.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            element.inputView = genderPicker
        }
        else if(index == 6)
        {
            element.frame = CGRect(x: (scrollViewWidth*4)-(scrollViewWidth/2)-(122), y: 222, width: 244, height: 49)
            element.background = UIImage(named:"SetupTextField")
            element.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 24.0)
            element.textAlignment = .center
            element.placeholder = "Favorite Type"
            element.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            element.inputView = typePicker
        }
        else if(index == 7)
        {
            element.frame = CGRect(x: (scrollViewWidth*4)-(scrollViewWidth/2)-(122), y: 327, width: 244, height: 49)
            element.background = UIImage(named:"SetupTextField")
            element.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 24.0)
            element.textAlignment = .center
            element.placeholder = "Eye Color"
            element.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            element.inputView = colorPicker
        }
        else if(index == 8)
        {
            element.frame = CGRect(x: (scrollViewWidth*4)-(scrollViewWidth/2)-(122), y: 432, width: 244, height: 49)
            element.background = UIImage(named:"SetupTextField")
            element.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 24.0)
            element.textAlignment = .center
            element.placeholder = "Height"
            element.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            element.returnKeyType = .done
        }
        else if(index == 9)
        {
            element.frame = CGRect(x: (scrollViewWidth*4)-(scrollViewWidth/2)-(122), y: 534, width: 244, height: 49)
            element.background = UIImage(named:"SetupTextField")
            element.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 24.0)
            element.textAlignment = .center
            element.placeholder = "Weight"
            element.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            element.keyboardType = .decimalPad
            element.returnKeyType = .done
        }
    }

    let swipeArrow = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:(scrollViewWidth/2)-(170/2), y: scrollViewHeight-120, width:170, height: 60))
    swipeArrow.image = UIImage(named: "WelcomeSwipeToContinue")
    swipeArrow.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    let getStartedButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:((scrollViewWidth*5) + scrollViewWidth/2)-125, y: scrollViewHeight-175, width: 250, height: 99))
    getStartedButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "GetStartedButton"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    getStartedButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(finishSetup), for: .touchUpInside)


    self.sideScrollView.addSubview(imgOne)

    self.sideScrollView.addSubview(messageOne)

    self.sideScrollView.addSubview(titleOne)
    self.sideScrollView.addSubview(titleTwo)
    self.sideScrollView.addSubview(titleThree)
    self.sideScrollView.addSubview(titleFour)
    self.sideScrollView.addSubview(titleFive)
    self.sideScrollView.addSubview(titleSix)

    self.sideScrollView.addSubview(swipeArrow)

    for fieldName in inputFields
    {
        self.sideScrollView.addSubview(fieldName)
    }

    self.sideScrollView.addSubview(getStartedButton)

    self.sideScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.sideScrollView.frame.width * 6, height:self.sideScrollView.frame.height)
    self.sideScrollView.delegate = self
    //self.pageControl.currentPage = 0

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach to use with `scrollView` is to add a `UIView` inside a `scrollView` (name it `contentView`). Then put everything inside this `contentView`. All your constraints will be based on the `contentView`. Then all you have to do is manipulate `contentView`'s frame to adjust the `scrollView`

Comment: Okay, but wouldn't that mess with spacing across pages? Also, how do I do that in Main.storyboard for each page?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by across pages? Are you using the same scrollView across different viewControllers?